# Git revert not bringing back the earlier state

Tags: git, git-revert

So a long time ago I  added a folder abc with a group of files in it to my project and made a commit with revision xyz.
After many commits someone has erased the folder with git rm -r abc.
After this there has been a lot of commits as well.

Now I need to get back the folder abc. I do

```
git revert xyz
```

After this I can find folder xyz but not all of the files that were added in the commit xyz are present.

What am I doing wrong? I dont want to do reset because I want to keep the history between commit xyz and the present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git revert xyz` does not bring your code back to the state in which it was at revision `xyz` - it creates a new commit that *undoes* whatever was done in `xyz`. You could try `git cherry-pick --no-commit xyz`, which will *replay* the changes that were done in `xyz` (if you leave out `--no-commit`, it will automatically become a new commit, but maybe you don't want everything that was done in `xyz`).

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I thought git revert xyz reverts all the modifications until revision xyz.

Comment: @jjei - if you ever wanted to actually do that (revert everything since xyz), then command you'd want is `git checkout xyz -- .` (while at the top level of the repository. (Or, if you didn't care about wiping out all of the history, you could just use `git reset --hard xyz` - but that is a potentially dangerous command.)

Answer (score 5):

What you really want is this:

```
git checkout xyz -- abc
```

That says "get me the version of the stuff at path `abc`, as it was in commit `xyz`". That way, you'll get your folder back in the state you committed it, but you won't touch any other files that may have been modified since.

(The `--` isn't necessary if you're explicitly specifying the commit, unless the name of the commit happens to also be a filename in your project. For instance, if you're trying to check out the version of a file named `HEAD` from the commit pointed to by `master`, you'd need to do `git checkout master -- HEAD`. *[Just save yourself the time and don't name your branches and tags the same things as your files.]*)

You don't want `git revert xyz` because that's for creating commits that reverse other commits, and you obviously don't want to *reverse* your *adding* the files in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! git checkout xyz -- abc did just the thing I wanted.